# A function that gives a number between 0 and 1 when given a definite range of function values.

Tags: calculus, functions

I have a number which is going up to 734 from 0 and I want to have a function that gives me a 1 if the function value is 734, 0 when the value is 0 and 0.5 when the value is 367.

Dont know if this is a simple problem or not but I would be glad if someone could help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want the function to be monotonically increasing as well? Or can it take any values in between? I can give you a quadratic function that satisfies this criterion quite easily, but I'm not sure that's what you want.

Comment: It would be good if it can take any values in between, this was more of an example. I tried something with the sinus function because I know that I get a number between -1 and 1 atleast there but Im not really good in math so I couldnt figure it out.

Comment: Have you tried [division](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B0%2F734%2C367%2F734%2C734%2F734%7D&x=0&y=0)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

You want your function to satisfy three points: $(734,1), (0,0), (367,0.5)$. These three points are collinear (they lie on the same line), so the function you want is linear and has a form $f(x)=ax+b$.

Now, use two of these three points to solve for $a$ and $b$.

Note:

If points given were not collinear, then we would have to solve quadratic equation $f(x)=a^2+bx+c$ to obtain a function that goes through those three points.

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer! This is definitely a really good hint and I will try it now.

Comment: You can use a very well known formula for the equation of a line through two points: $y-y_1=\dfrac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}(x-x_1)$, where $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ are two points on a line.

Comment: Yes I used exactly this formula. (0.5 - 0) / (367 - 0) = 0.00136239782 so this is the pitch. Now I just need to adjust the linear function to b. So the linear function looks like: 1 = 0.00136239782 * 0 + b | adjust to b: 1/(0.001362) - 0 = b. is this right?

Comment: There should be 0 on the left side, not 1. So, it should be $0=0.001362\cdot 0+b$ because we are using point $(0,0)$, and result for $b$ is 0. Also, notice that the line goes through origin, so you could have concluded that $b=0$ right from the start :)

Comment: Thank you so much! I have to re learn all this stuff. I had never the slightest interest in maths at the school but slowly Im getting interested in it when I walk into problems like these. Maybe I will buy good book or something.